# WiX custom action - running application in Target directory

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am using WiX to install a certain EXE file. I want the WiX setup to end running the EXE file (and not leaving any window opened), so I am using:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" FileKey="APPFileKey" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no" />
```

The only issue is that it runs the application with current directory being the place where I run the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer).

And I need this application to be running where the user choose to install it - it causes me many issues. Is it possible to tell WiX where to run the custom action?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve exactly the same behavior as you got 15 years ago. Would you care to share .wxs file that makes running an .exe file from the same folder .msi was run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the *[Directory attribute of CustomAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm)* to specify a working directory.

It doesn't work with FileKey, but it works with ExeCommand. Instead of FileKey, you can set ExeCommand to something like "[TARGETDIR]file.exe".

Comment: The Directory atribute in CustomAction isn't letting me use a bracketized value, like [TARGETDIR]. Is this possible?

Comment: FYI you don't need the square brackets when using directory constants in the Directory attribute. E.g. use Directory="TARGETDIR"

Answer (score 0):

here is an example, that runs "tinytask.exe" from the folder the product was installed in

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="RunONLYTinyTask" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="TS" UpgradeCode="{E7A6D8C2-9F05-4A0F-B7C2-91A3B9D35F24}">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="PlDemo"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="RunTinyTask" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
        </Feature>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="RunTinyTaskComponent" Guid="{E7A6D8C2-9F05-4A0F-B7C2-91A3B9D35F24}">
                <File Source="tinytask.exe"/>
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="RunTinyTask" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <CustomAction Id="RunTinyTask" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]tinytask.exe" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
    </Fragment> 
</Wix>
```